# Will Samsung Fast Charge charge a QC 2.0 device as

Tags: charging

I have seen that Samsung phones can fast charge on both Qualcomm Quick Charge  and  Samsung Fast Charge adapters.

But I am unclear if you want to charge a HTC/Sony etc Qualcomm 2.0 device if the Samsung Fast Charge chargers will charge the device similarly to a dedicated quick charge 2.0 charger?

Comment: Re your comment on my now  deleted answer -1. Yes, both Qualcomm and fast charging are different but not much 2. Fast charging supports [Qualcomm also as you can see on Samsung site](http://www.samsung.com/ie/support/skp/faq/1074414). Since it supports both, and it does have Qualcomm certification ( as I recollect), arguments given in the answer were valid. Deleted my answer since it *appeared to you* that I missed understood the question

Comment: To be fair, I should have clarified this in my answer as well

Comment: I understand that page saying that Samsung fast charge phones will work with both QC chargers and Samsung fast chargers. Where do you see that the fast chargers work with non Samsung QC phones?

Comment: Elsewhere on the web. But more importantly, once it supports QC charging and is compliant to standard, it has to behave like QC compliant phones in supporting other devices- that's the purpose of standardisation

Comment: My device, Moto X Play uses *Turbo Charging* but is QC compliant and works on other brand devices to quick charge

Comment: you are not addressing the issue that the Samsung fast charger is not QC and does not have the QC logo.  Where does it say that the charger is QC compliant?  That is the question.  The samsung phones are both QC and fast charge compliant. Where do you see the charger is compliant to QC standards?  Your moto X is the phone that is compliant not the charger.

Comment: You are right **if** the charger does not have QC logo and I remember reading that it had (not sure for which Samsung phone) and as mentioned in first comment. You are also right about Moto X. Charger is not QC compliant. Which is the model of your device... Let's see if we can get more inputs on that- Samsung is known for changes across models

Comment: the charger does not have QC logo.  I had a pic on the answer you deleted.  The question is - is the samsung fast charger QC compliant.    iBugs answer was of course.  I was told otherwise in a shop.  Hence the question if it was tested on a non samsung device, as I presume the shop guy has no idea.  iBug tested the Voltage so for sure the QC device can get the higher charge.  So my question moves to are there benefits to using an actual QC charger, as in 12V over 9V.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54492/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-jon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.
Samsung Fast Charge is basically an alias for Qualcomm QC 2.0/3.0 (for S7/S7 edge). They are totally compatible with each other.

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: I have a nubia Z9 NX508J using a Samsung S6 edge stock charger. The charger outputs 1.55A @ 8.96V, read with a USB meter. Then I got an ordinary phone and the charger started outputting 0.98A @ 5.11V. That's where my conclusion is drawn from. The QC 3.0 part is what I guess but I think it's true.

Comment: I see QC goes also does 12V.  Fast Charge does 9V.  Would your Z9 charge faster with a QC2 charger?

Comment: It'a bit faster but mu USB meter can't exceed 10V. I suppose it takes 1/6 less time as the 12V charger outputs 1.5A.